# Location Method in Android not working

Tags: java, android, location

I am following a tutorial, and I got stuck on some code. The problem is that I am not able to get the current coordinates into my textView(id:red), and it doesnt change state. The error, I suspect, is that the method `onLocationChanged()` is not being called. I am enclosing my Java Program and my layout xml file as well. Thank You for all the help!

Android MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.wepicit;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationListener;

import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.model.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    protected Context context;
    String lat;
    String provider; 
    protected String gps_enabled,network_enabled;
    Button button;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        newLocation.set(location);
        //System.out.println("Lat:"+ location.getLatitude() +" Long:"+ location.getLongitude());
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.red);
        text.setText("Lat:"+ newLocation.getLatitude() +" Long:"+ newLocation.getLongitude());
        Log.d("Lat:"+ newLocation.getLatitude() +" Long:"+ newLocation.getLongitude(), gps_enabled);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Latitude","disable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Latitude","enable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Latitude","status");
    }

}
```

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="Tester" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: make sure your gps is on.

Comment: Yup, GPS satellites are enabled, and 'Access to my location' option is checked as well. Location services do turn on when I access the app on my Moto X.

Comment: If the permission android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is missing in the manifest (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);returns null

Comment: Sorry, I should have included my manifest in the first place, however I have both COARSE_LOCATION and FINE_LOCATION user permissions included in the xml file. I believe the error comes because the method onLocationChanged() does not get called. I am not sure on how to fix it :(.

Comment: i had similar problem when i worked with it first but then i changed my code and its working i can post it if you want

Comment: i think below piece of code should be in oncreate `Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);`

Comment: If I had that line in onCreate(), it would no longer be in the scope of the function,onLocationChanged(). If you could post some code, it would be great :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36983/discussion-between-karan-mer-and-chaitanya-varanasi)

Comment: Your code is good (y), all what you need is make sure that **GPS in enabled** in your device , and make sure you have added the permission `FINE_LOCATION` in your manifest file, and you should request updates from `NETWORK_PROVIDER` too because updates from GPS takes a long time, and sometimes if you are in a building, it's hard to get the values of GPS.

Comment: Chaitanya have you read about the fused location provider !